# Leaflet - ¿Cómo sacar la información de una capa de mi mapa?

Tags: base-de-datos, leaflet, openlayers, mapa

Cuando se clica el mapa, aparece un "pop-up" mostrando un código de referencia. Este código lo obtiene de `source.getLayer`. Este código es único para cada área de tierra, que pertenece a algún ciudadano.
Lo que quiero exactamente es añadir información específica a cada código de referencia. Por lo tanto, necesito unir el código de referencia con su información correspondiente en mi base de datos, por ejemplo y luego llamarlo desde un "div".

Aquí podéis ver a lo que me refiero: [Imagen de un código de referencia aleatorio de mi mapa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9iz5.jpg)

El código es el siguiente:

```
        var capaCatastroTodo = L.tileLayer.wms("https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/Cartografia/GeneraMapa.aspx?", {
               layers: "CATASTRO",
               format: 'image/png',
               transparent: true,
               version: '1.1.1',
               attribution: "DIRECCION GENERAL DEL CATASTRO"
        });

        var source = L.WMS.source("https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/Cartografia/GeneraMapa.aspx?", {
            opacity: 0.2,
        });

        source.getLayer("PARCELA").addTo(map);
```

¿Alguien sabría cómo obtener la información de la capa a través de `source.getlayer("PARCELA")` y añadirla a mi base de datos? Esto es lo que hace que el código de referencia aparezca al mapa al hacer clic.

¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Puede hacer un print de `source.getlayer("PARCELA")`?

Comment: Con un alert aparece: [object Object]

Comment: Con var_dump() o print_r

Comment: Sólo puedo usar console.log, ya que es un archivo .js y obtengo lo siguiente: https://prnt.sc/shglpc
Si hago el archivo .php y luego uso <script>, no me funciona tampoco